# Python won't rewrite file with first line removed using readlines() and for loop

Tags: python, string, file-io, web-scraping

I' writing a web scraping script in Python that pulls an 'ID' from the first line of a text file and appends it to a partial URL; then downloads an image from said URL. Everything works fine, but when I run it using the third function (which contains the actual code for downloading - this works fine) it doesn't update the text file by deleting the first line.

I'm sure there is something I am missing here, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
def delete_used_id():
    # open and save all ids
    id_file_r = open('C:/Users/my.name/Documents/IDs.txt', 'r')
    lines = id_file_r.readlines()
    first_line_unf = str(lines[0])[3:]
    first_line = first_line_unf.strip()
    id_file_r.close()
    # reopen in write mode
    id_file_w = open('C:/Users/my.name/Documents/IDs.txt','w')
    for unused_id in lines:
        if unused_id != first_line:
            id_file_w.write(unused_id)
    id_file_w.close()
    print("Deleting used ID: " + first_line)

def get_id_from_file():
    id_file = open('C:/Users/my.name/Documents/IDs.txt', 'r')
    # slice the first 3 chars off of the string
    farmer_id_unf = id_file.readline()[3:]
    farmer_id = farmer_id_unf.strip()
    print("Getting Farmer ID: " + farmer_id)
    return farmer_id
```

Comment: How can `unused_id` (the whole first line) ever be equal to `first_line` (the first line, without its first three characters, `strip`ped)? Why not just `for line in lines[1:]:`?

Comment: when you say 'for line in lines[1:]:' will this do the same thing as '[3:]' ?

Comment: Looks like your issue is your if condition in `delete_used_id`.  You read in the first `line[3:]`, and then check `unused_id` against it. Logically, it's similar to checking if `"foobar"[3:] == "foobar" `, the first will only be `bar`.

Comment: `lines[1:]` is a slice of a list, rather than a string (`lines[0][3:]`) but otherwise yes; all elements except the `0`th.

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys jonrsharpe's solution worked!

Comment: A suggestion: Unless you have some reason for fetching the URLs in top down order it would be more efficient to process your ID list from the bottom up. So you fetch the URL corresponding to the last ID in the file and then use `file.truncate()` to delete the last line in the file. Of course, you'll need to calculate the byte offset in 'IDs.txt' where the 2nd last line ends, but that's easy: you can just sum the lengths of all the strings `lines[:-1]`.

Comment: That is a much more efficient way of doing this task, but as I have a very looming deadline, and I wouldn't be able to test it in time, I will have to refactor my script to incorporate your ideas in the near future. Thanks though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to jonrsharpe and nerdwaller:

**ANSWER:**

```
def delete_used_id():
    # open and save all ids
    id_file_r = open('C:/Users/my.name/Documents/IDs.txt', 'r')
    lines = id_file_r.readlines()
    first_line_unf = lines[0][3:]
    first_line = first_line_unf.strip()
    id_file_r.close()
    # reopen in write mode
    id_file_w = open('C:/Users/my.name/Documents/IDs.txt','w')
    for line in lines[1:]:
        id_file_w.write(line)
    id_file_w.close()
    print("Deleting used ID: " + first_line)
```

Comment: You don't need the `if line != first_line:` because `lines[1:]` is a list of all the lines except the first.

Comment: Thanks @PM 2Ring, will refactor this now :)